# Bubble sort a linked list Structure of Strings, Ints and Floats in C

Tags: c, sorting, structure

I am having trouble with the bubble sorting of my linked list, I populate the linked list by reading from a file (I can include this function and file as well if necessary) I am not receiving any compiler errors; however, when I run the program the linked list is not sorting itself at all. Using debug statements I found that the program will enter into the swap function but it is not rearranging the values of the structure parts. Does anyone have any solutions to this? I have included my code for defining the structure and the code of the bubble sort and swap function where the problem arises.

```
 struct character {  /*define character_t structure*/
      char fname[STRSZ];
      char lname[STRSZ];
      int seas;
      char state;
      float height;
      struct character *next;
    };
    typedef struct character character_t;



    void bubbleSort(character_t *start){
      int swapped,i;
      character_t *ptr1;
      character_t *lptr = NULL;

     do{
       swapped=0;
       ptr1=start;

       while(ptr1->next!=lptr)
       {
         if(strcmp(ptr1->fname,ptr1->next->fname)>0)
         {
           swap(ptr1,ptr1->next);
         }
         ptr1=ptr1->next;
       }
       lptr=ptr1;
     }
     while(swapped);
    }

    void swap(struct character *a,struct character *b){
      char tfname[898]=" ";
      char tlname[898]= " ";
      int tseas;
      char tstate;
      float theight;

      strcpy(tfname,a->fname);
      strcpy(a->fname,b->name);
      strcpy(b->fname,tfname);

      strcpy(tfname,a->fname);
      strcpy(a->fname,b->fname);
      strcpy(b->fname,tfname);

      tseas=a->seas;
      a->seas=b->seas;
      b->seas=tseas;

      tstate=a->state;
      a->state=b->state;
      b->state=tstate;

      theight=a->height;
      a->height=b->height;
      b->height=theight;
    }
```

Comment: `while(swapped)` is the same as `while(0)` since you initialize `swapped` to 0, and never change it.

Comment: Thanks that helped and also I just had lname instead of fname.